# reading from multiple files using wild character in perl

Tags: perl

Suppose I have 5 files: `tmp1.txt`, `tmp2.txt`, `tmp3.txt`, `temp1.txt`, `temp2.txt`.

Now is there any way to open multiple files and read from them using wilcards.

Example,

1. If I write `"t*.txt"` then data from each file should be read.
2. If I write `"tm*.txt"` then only data from 3 files should be read.

Comment: did you tried checking perldocs? tried google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `glob`, assuming these files exist in a local directory, and no other files with similar names are in that directory.

```
print "Read which files? ";
chomp(my $glob = <STDIN>);
my @files_to_read = glob $glob;
```

Of course, you can assure that you get no other files by filtering them

```
my %valid = map { $_ => 1 } qw(tmp1 tmp2 tmp3 temp1 temp2);
@files = grep $valid{$_}, glob $glob;
```

The first statement creates a hash where the valid file name keys have a true value, the other statement runs this check on the elements of the glob list.

Comment: So after getting a hash of the files, how to read from it. I mean, how to assign filehandler to these files? Will there be one handler for 1 file? Sorry, I'm not getting it.

Comment: Are you asking how to open a file in perl?

Comment: @bookishq, Whenever you want to do something repeatedly, you need some for of looping, perhaps `for my $qfn (@qfns) { open(my $fh, '<', $qfn) or die $!; ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob` to find the list of files, and read through them sequentially by assigning the list to `@ARGV`, which emulates them being passed on the command line.

```
our @ARGV = glob '/path/to/tm*.txt';

while (<ARGV>) {
  print;
}
```

Comment: `if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') { @ARGV = map glob, @ARGV }`  ;-)

Comment: @TLP: Yeah, if the filename pattern is passed as a command-line parameter.